# iOS UITests failed: IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=13

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, xcodebuild, xcode-ui-testing

I am running an AppUITests for an iOS app from Jenkins build script. Unit tests (AppTests) running fine but AppUITests are failed because of the below issue. How can I resolve this issue?

> 09:19:53.506 XCTRunner[22911:77924] Failed to background test runner
>   within 30.0s. 09:19:53.507 xcodebuild[22835:77541]
>   -[IDETestOperationCoordinator testRunnerSession:initializationForUITestingDidFailWithError:]
>   09:19:53.507 XCTRunner[22911:77924] Calling completion. 09:19:53.507
>   xcodebuild[22835:77541] Test operation failure: Failed to background
>   test runner. 09:19:53.507 xcodebuild[22835:77541]
>   _finishWithError:**Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=13 "Failed to background test runner.**"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to background test runner.}
>   didCancel: 1

Comment: Looks like test is failing to launch the simulator before xcode shuts the test down due to timeout, does the same pipeline run fine in your local mac ?

Comment: yes it works fine @u.gen

Comment: I have the same problem, but this error appears only if I "delete" and recreate all simulators with `SNAPSHOT_FORCE_DELETE=yes fastlane  snapshot reset_simulators`

Comment: are you running it in script of jenkins or qb?

Comment: I'm working with fastlane (sorry for the late answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue in our app. It was caused by a permission alert displayed on launch (APN in this case, but it's likely to be the same for any other alert).

## Steps to reproduce

- use an app which will display a permission alert on launch
- make sure the simulator is clean (in order to show the alert)
- run all Tests

## Result

- app launches, shows the alert and runs the (normal) Tests just fine
- **BUT** when coming to UITests, the simulator will stay black and after a short while, it fails with following error:

> Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=13 "Failed to
> background test runner.

## Solution

Run the UITests before the normal Tests (just change the order in `edit scheme` => `Test` => `Info`)

**Notes:**

- Maybe you have to make sure, the UITests will handle the alert by using `XTest`s `addUIInterruptionMonitor` method. Or otherwise it could be possible the (normal) Tests will fail the same way (didn't test this scenario).
- If you really don't want to run the UITests first, you could add an additional UITest target, which is run first, and just handles the alert. Then you should be able to run the (normal) Tests followed by your UITests.

## Related

- https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/test-ui-xcode-9/2313

Comment: Using Xcode 9.4.1 and just rearranging the tests targets from the scheme did not work for me. Actually no diff in the xcscheme file is made at all. Removing and adding the test targets in correct order to the scheme made it work.